# knockout custom binding to access observableArray data with dynamic property name

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to create a custom binding handler in knockout to total columns of data. I have an application where I need to total many columns of data and thought a custom binding handler would do the trick.

Example binding:

```
<span data-bind="totalAmount: Adjustments, columnName:'Amount'"></span>
```

The custom binding handler looks something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.totalAmount = {
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var val = valueAccessor();
    var unwrappedVal = ko.unwrap(val);

    var columnName = allBindings().columnName;
    var total = 0;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(unwrappedVal, function (item) {
        var amt = item.<columnName>();
        total += amt;
    });

    $(element).html("$" + total);
}
```

}

In the code above, how do I get the value of the observable associated with the propery passed in via the columnName property?

Comment: What about `var amt = item[columnName]();` (or even better: `var amt = ko.unwrap(item[columnName]);` ? In javascript you can reference properties by their name using the array indexer syntax.

Comment: Worked like a champ! Thanks.